# How to run JavaScript code once the connection is established?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, connection, reveal.js

As a Node.js newbie I am trying to change the [Smartphone Remote Control with Node.js and Socket.io](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/smartphone-remote-control-for-presentations/) example by Nick Anastasov so that a password is not required.

In the original source code the **app.js** file sends `{ access : 'granted' }` after the word *kittens* has been entered into a web form and the **script.js** starts its main tasks, for example unblurs the web page:

```
socket.on('access', function(data) {
    if (data.access === "granted") {  // XXX Tried removing this line

        blurredElements.removeClass('blurred');
        form.hide();

        $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
            // ....
        });

        socket.on('navigate', function(data) {
            // ....
        });
    }
});
```

I have changed the **app.js** so that it does not emit `access` at all.

Then I have tried removing just the line `if (data.access === "granted")` from **script.js**, but this of course hasn't worked: the web page stays blurred, because no `access` event is received anymore (neither `granted`, nor `denied`).

My question is: how should I please change the above code, so that it is run once the connection is established?

Should I maybe use `socket.on('connect')` or `socket.on('connection')` or is it same problem (since there is no string `connect` being sent)?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Brad (thank you!) I have changed the string in **script.js** from "access" to "connection", but the web page stays blurred - here is the complete source code:

```
$(function() {
    Reveal.initialize({
        history: true
    });

    var socket = io();
    var presentation = $('.reveal');

    socket.on('connection', function(data){ // XXX changed this

                presentation.removeClass('blurred'); // XXX not called
                var ignore = false;

                $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
                        if (ignore){
                                return;
                        }
                        var hash = window.location.hash;
                        socket.emit('slide-changed', {
                                hash: hash
                        });
                });

                socket.on('navigate', function(data){
                        window.location.hash = data.hash;
                        ignore = true;
                        setInterval(function () {
                                ignore = false;
                        },100);
                });
    });
});
```

And here is the complete **app.js** source code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var presentation = io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('slide-changed', function(data){
                presentation.emit('navigate', {
                        hash: data.hash
                });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want `io.on('connection')`.  This event is fired any time a new client connects.

http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: So "connection" is special, not like "access"? And do you mean `io.on('connection')` or `socket.on('connection')` in my case?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Newer versions of Socket.IO document as assigning the object to `io`, but it doesn't matter what you call it.  `socket` seems correct for what you are doing.  The `connection` event is fired from within Socket.IO itself.  It's not a remotely fired event.

Comment: I have change to `socket.on('connection')` but the web page stays blurred. Could you please take a look at my updated question - where I list the complete source code?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Oh, the `connection` event is on the server.  If you want to track that client-side, you need the `connect` event as documented here:  http://socket.io/docs/client-api/